# Unable to use SOCKET IO in Node-React Application @Heroku

Tags: heroku, socket.io

My application is working perfectly fine. Yesterday i made some changes to include SOCKET.IO on server/client.

Since then i am not able to run the application, although the build is successful.

### Please find the logs:
import { Server } from "socket.io";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'socket.io' does not provide an export named 'Server'

Even after i tried to pull the exact object by calling the proper file, it is not working in Heroku.

import { Server } from "../node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js";

---

Everything is working in local.

I have checked the documentation where they have specified to use sticky session.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity

But how to enable it from dashboard?

Is there any build pack to resolve this?

thanks

Comment: It is not related to sticky session. did you add socket.io to package.json?

Comment: Yes, same build is working fine on my local. Entries for socket.io are both in client/server package.json

Comment: can you remove all package-lock files and node_modules. run npm install and tell me if it works on loca?

Comment: It is working in my local even after removing the files and rebuilding. Something not correct with the way Heroku uses NODE build pack it seems.

Comment: Even after trying to be innovative by doig this:

import { Server } from "../node_modules/socket.io/dist/index.js";

it is not working in Heroku